# Intellij Java cannot find symbol

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a problem with my Intellij project.

[image: Screenshot]

I've already updated my Java JDK and JRE.
Someone have another solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api attached to your sources?

Comment: Try with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589152/intellij-idea-cannot-resolve-import-javax-servlet

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html

Comment: May be you need following dependency
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

Comment: Already did this solutions. But none of them works.

Comment: Here some suggests, follow the link below:
[click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193228/compile-error-package-javax-servlet-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 2):

If you have already imported this project as maven.
Do mvn idea:idea

Else add framework support > maven 
and then do mvn clean/mvn idea:idea

Comment: It's not imported as maven.

Comment: If its not maven, is it some other build framework like gradle?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use Mven or Gradle for dependency management, add the dependency on the `javax.servlet-api.jar` to the [module's dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies) manually.

If you use application server (e.g. Tomcat) you should to [define it in IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-and-managing-application-server-integration.html) and IDE will create java-ee library that you can then add to the module's dependencies:

[image]

[image]